# Finding similar dates based on columns

Tags: mysql

I have a input like this

```
+------+------------+-----------+
| col1 | Start date | End date  |
+------+------------+-----------+
| A    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| A    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| B    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| B    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| F    | 1/26/2021  | 2/25/2022 |
| G    | 1/26/2021  | 2/25/2022 |
| D    | 1/26/2020  | 2/25/2022 |
| E    | 1/26/2020  | 2/25/2022 |
| C    | 10/28/2019 | 12/7/2020 |
| C    | 10/26/2019 | 8/27/2020 |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

CREATE TABLE Table1
(`col1` varchar(1), `Start date` datetime, `End date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
(`col1`, `Start date`, `End date`)
VALUES
('A', '2021-02-25 00:00:00', '2022-04-26 00:00:00'),
('A', '2021-02-25 00:00:00', '2022-04-26 00:00:00'),
('B', '2021-02-25 00:00:00', '2022-04-26 00:00:00'),
('B', '2021-02-25 00:00:00', '2022-04-26 00:00:00'),
('F', '2021-01-26 00:00:00', '2022-02-25 00:00:00'),
('G', '2021-01-26 00:00:00', '2022-02-25 00:00:00'),
('D', '2020-01-26 00:00:00', '2022-02-25 00:00:00'),
('E', '2020-01-26 00:00:00', '2022-02-25 00:00:00'),
('C', '2019-10-28 00:00:00', '2020-12-07 00:00:00'),
('C', '2019-10-26 00:00:00', '2020-08-27 00:00:00')
;

I am trying to write a query for col1 which have start date and end date within same year and display start date end date descending order

output like

```
+------+------------+-----------+
| col1 | Start date | End date  |
+------+------------+-----------+
| A    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| A    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| B    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| B    | 2/25/2021  | 4/26/2022 |
| F    | 1/26/2021  | 2/25/2022 |
| G    | 1/26/2021  | 2/25/2022 |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: this is what is coming out if i use the website which is mentioned - can you guide

Comment: Well, it's getting better. What website?

Comment: I have used this https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: I never liked that part of that answer (I didn't write that bit). I've removed it.